# Run Raspberry Pi 3 as VPN access point with pi-hole

Tags: pi-3, vpn, dns, access-point, pi-hole

I've got my Raspberry Pi  with Raspbian running as pi-hole, connected through Wi-Fi to OpenVPN with most of my devices, where it blocks ads. I'd like to set RPI as VPN access point without reinstalling Raspbian or pi-hole as it was in one guide. Any help would be much appreciated.